# jQuery parameters not passed to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-load, url-parameters

I am not sure why but jQuery is not passing parameters to PHP in order to complete the load() function with specific data based on the parameters ID.

In short term, when a user clicks a link there is onclick which fires up `photo_tab('.$row['id'].');`

account.php HTML element

```
<li><a href="#!/photos" onclick="photo_tab('.$row['id'].');"><i class="icon-camera"></i> Photos</a></li>
```

In a sence the ID should be passed to the photo_tab (the script is included into page not on the page it self)

general.js

```
function photo_tab(user_id) {
    $('.ac-content').load('ajax/photos.php',{user_id:id});
}
```

And photos/ page should be loaded which is a PHP page and based on the user_id value load photos from database associated with that user_id.

```
<?php
   if ($_GET['user_id'] == 2) {
      echo "WORKED!";
   } else {
      echo "FAILED!";
   } 

***this is the photos/ file located at ajax/photos.php with mod_rewrite to point
otherwise to just photos/ or photos
```

EDIT: 1 - Using full path instead of rewrite photos > ajax/photos.php does not work
      2 - The ID is being passed and echoed onto page via $row['ID'];
      3 - ajax/photos.php is using $_REQUEST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing the data as a query string, like so:

```
function photo_tab(user_id) {
    $('.ac-content').load('photos/','user_id='+id);
}
```

**EDIT:**
Giving this a second look, is that URL correct? It seems weird to have a relative URL.

You should also make sure the generated markup is correct, is the row ID printing out in the source?

**EDIT 2:**
I set this up locally, this is working code, mimicking your file structure.

//localhost/account.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function photo_tab(id) {
            $('.ac-content').load(
                'ajax/photos.php',
                { 'user_id': id }
            );
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="ac-content"></div>
    <a href="#!/photos" onclick="photo_tab(3);"><i class="icon-camera"></i> Photos</a>
</body>
```

//localhost/ajax/photos.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['user_id']) && $_GET['user_id'] == 2)
{
    echo "WORKED!";
}
else
{
    echo "FAILED!";
}
```

Comment: This could potentially work, but in this case there is no luck, its either the onclick is failing to trigger the photo_tab function or .load() is not working as it should

Comment: Yes, onclick="photo_tab(2);" 2 being my user ID from $row['id'] which is correct so the ID is being added to the href element which should use onclick to trigger the event, also I did change photos/ to ajax/photos.php still nothing

Comment: There's something wrong with that URL. Are you rewriting the URL? **Edit:** Just saw you are indeed. What's the URL of the page you're making the request from?

Comment: As I mention in other comments even using direct URL path does not work ajax/photos.php (<--actuall path) or photos/ or photos non work

Comment: That's a relative path. It depends on the current URL you're making the request from. If you're working from the root of the domain, try adding a slash at the beginning of it.

Comment: I am working from account.php should have no problem accessing/making request to AJAX directory in the same folder

Comment: I just set this up locally and the code I posted in the edit works. Check it out.

Comment: Yes I did test it with embeding the JS into the page that seems to work, but not from external JS file which is very odd

Comment: Open the console (usually F12) and have a look at what the .js file is returning. You should see it under the Network tab, you may have to refresh after you opened it.

Comment: Its returning application/javascript for some reason instead of text/javascript

Comment: Is your script tag correct in account.php? The type attribute is required unless you have the HTML5 doctype.

Comment: I am using HTML5 doctype and I am following every rule, I double checked. It jsut that photo_tab does not want to work from general.js but works like a charm from the account.php page

Answer (score 1):

How about wrapping your variable in quotes?

```
function photo_tab(id)
{
    $('.ac-content').load('photos/',{'user_id':id});
}
```

Comment: Nope, it looks like the .load() is not even bothering to process the URL its not even returning a FAILED! echo.

Comment: Try adding a function to see what kicks off after everything renders. `function photo_tab(id)
{
    $('.ac-content').load('photos/',{'user_id':id},function(r){alert(r)});
}`

Comment: Nothing, no alert even being return. Ok this is very odd then

Comment: the photos folder resides on the same level as your jquery file? Maybe it cannot locate the folder?

Comment: actually even using direct path without re-write as ajax/photos.php still returns nothing

Comment: If you're using Chrome try to `console.log(id)` to see what you get. Then try to do something outside your conditional to see if the php file is even being kicked off.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: photo_tab is not defined account:39
onclick

Answer (score 1):

Yes parameters should not be passed as you supposed because as the name intends method load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element.

```
.load( url [, data ] [, complete(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) ] )
```

EG : Same as above, but will POST the additional parameters to the server and a callback that is executed when the server is finished responding.

```
$(".ac-content").load("photos.php", {user_id:user_id}, function(){
  alert("have been loaded");
});
```

Try the above syntax.

1. Try `$_REQUEST` instead `$_GET`
2. It should `photos.php` or some .php not `photos/`
3. Make sure `id` is not null.

Comment: Nope nothing is being returned not even alert, also photos/ did work with a basic .load() without passing any values to it, so its not a problem even using photos/ direct path as ajax/photos.php did not do much nor changing $_GET to $_REQUEST

Comment: 1 - Done (FAILED TO LOAD), 2 - Done (ajax/photos.php  FAILED TO LOAD), 3 - Done ( onclick="photo_tab(2);" is being passed to page  FAILED TO LOAD)

Comment: check updated answer. change user_id:id to user_id:user_id and check

Comment: let me know what's the outcome

Comment: Nothing no alert or anything

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: photo_tab is not defined account:39
onclick

Comment: it means photo_tab method is not accessible. general.js is not included correctly. make sure it's included correctly

Comment: But it is included correctly echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="' . $javascript . '"</script>' . "\n"; and based on the Page.php class $this->addJavascript('http://sitename.tld/folder/js/general.js');

Comment: check the head section of your html and see whether general.js is included]

Comment: Yes it is included in the page but Chrome still gives me not defined

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `id` was never defined. Try this:

```
function photo_tab(id) {
  $('.ac-content').load('photos/',{user_id:id});
}
```

Comment: Nope still no luck, its seems like the .load() part is not working and not loading into .ac-content div

Comment: I added a URL structure as well maybe that can solve few things, the function photo_tab is being loaded from general.js which wraps all things with $(document).ready(function() but I dough this is the issue